# Heroku: Really slow connect times to RDS

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, latency, rds

We're stumped by this, been trying to solve it for a month. It looks like every once in a while (maybe one in 100 requests) our connection time to RDS or RabbitMQ takes > 0.5 seconds.

We're using Heroku with Django, amazon RDS and S3 (we do tons of image uploads).

Here's a sample slow connection (fast connections are really fast, like < 20 ms):

[image]

It's worth mentioning both Heroku and RDS are in the us-east region. Also when we use Redis Cloud (Heroku add-on) we see slow connection speeds to that too.

**UPDATE:**

I've also found that these same delays exist for Memcached. In fact, on average Memcached takes roughly the same amount as a request to the database. I'm just using Memcached for storing API keys and there's plenty of memory left.

[image]

Comment: so what you mean is that one of 100 requests from some one ip x.x.x.x takes > 0.5 seconds ?

Answer (score 1):

It resembles something I read earlier on a blog where it seemed that on Heroku a request might be routed to a dyno that is handling a long running request. That way the old request blocks the execution of the next request. The routing isn't quite as "intelligent" as it is advertised.

I'm not 100% sure that this is the problem you are experiencing as is seems that the slowness shouldn't be in the connection but in the handling of the request to Heroku.

You can find more details on the problem describes here: http://news.rapgenius.com/James-somers-herokus-ugly-secret-lyrics

Comment: Yeah, I think the inefficient routing would cause longer than expected queuing times. Our queuing times are always really short though. Our traffic is about 100 rpm.

Comment: What webserver process are you using?